# How does the SessionFactory connection work with pgbouncer pool?

Tags: hibernate, connection-pooling, postgresql-9.4, sessionfactory, pgbouncer

We have a large simulation that is developed in java and each run of this simulation is a jar being run on a node in a grid. Typically ~3 thousand jobs run across a few grids. And in the jar are classes that use Hibernate to connect to a database and write out data to a pg database, where each job is a row in a table. So essentially each running job inserts and updates its own row.

But since each jar is essentially independent, each running jar creates a SessionFactory to do work and we quickly blow past the maximum number of connections to the database. I actually didn't realize the SessionFactory made a connection to the database. I only thought it opened connections to the database for work in transactions. So opening the session factory connections alone limit how many jobs can log their work.

We looked at pgbouncer and according to the documentation it seems connections are only issued during sessions or transactions. Does this include the connection made by the SessionFactory itself? As it stands each job, which can last for hours to days, keeps an open connection to the database because of the SessionFactory and all other jobs past max_connections are blocked.

Thanks for the help